# Update child's props from parent node

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'am trying to realize a filter for a collection of components (like DropDown menu) that have different boolean props.

Initially all my component are rendered but, when I do my choice on filter, I'd like to render only components that have a correlation with choice made.
For do that I've think that I should to have an array filled by my components and a container that it will be used with this method `ReactDOM(array,container)` only when component did mount.

The question is:
If I have a collection of components already rendered, all of them child of the same parent, is there a way for update dynamically them's props from parent node?
I'd like to do that for implement a conditionally rendering to the purpose of decide which component render.

```
 class EventsPlanned extends Component{ //the parent
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        showAllEvents: true,
        showUnmappedEvents: false,
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    var container = document.getElementById("eventToShowContainer");
    var arr=[];
    var eventsArrayJSON = localStorage.getItem("eventsArray");
    var eventsArray = JSON.parse(eventsArrayJSON);

    if(eventsArray.length !==0){
        for(let i=0; i<eventsArray.length; i++){
            arr.push(<Event key={i}
                        eventName={eventsArray[i].name} 
                        eventPhoto={eventsArray[i].photo} 
                        eventPeriods={eventsArray[i].periods} 
                        eventDescription={eventsArray[i].description}
                        eventTag={eventsArray[i].tag}
                        eventIsDraft={this.state.showAllEvents}
                        eventIsMapped={this.state.showUnmappedEvents}/>);
        }
        ReactDOM.render(arr, container);
    } else {
        ReactDOM.render(this.nothingToShow(), container);
    }
}

filterHandler = (item) =>{  //callback function for dropdown child
    switch(item){
        case "Events Planned":
            this.setState({
                showAllEvents: true,
                showUnmappedEvents: false,
            });
            break;
        case "Unmapped Events":
            this.setState({
                showAllEvents: false,
                showUnmappedEvents: true,
            });
            break;

nothingToShow = () =>{ //in case there aren't event
    return <div className="w3-container">
                <div className="w3-panel">
                    <h1>Nessun Evento da mostrare</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
}

render(){
    return(
            <div>
                <EventsHeader filterHandler={this.filterHandler}/>
                <div id="eventToShowContainer"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default EventsPlanned;


class Event extends Component{ // the child
    state={
        name: this.props.eventName,
        photo: this.props.eventPhoto,
        periods: this.props.eventPeriods,
        description: this.props.eventDescription,
        tag: this.props.eventTag,
        isDraft: this.props.eventIsDraft,
        showUnmapped: this.props.showUnmapped
    }

    render(){
        if(this.state.showUnmapped){
            return(
                <div className="w3-container">
                    <div className="eventPanel w3-panel">
                        <h1>name: {this.state.name}</h1>
                        <h6>description: {this.state.description}</h6>
                        <h6>{this.state.periods[0]}</h6>
                        <h6>{this.state.tag[0]}</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default Event;
```

Comment: can you post some code that you already tried yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so, first, you need to render all children in parent's `render` method.

Remove any render logic from `componentDidMount` and render all of the markup in `render` method directly:

```
// EventsPlanned component
state = {
  events: [],
  showEvents: false,
  showUnmappedEvents: false,
}

componentDidMount() {
  const eventsArrayJSON = localStorage.getItem("eventsArray");
  const events = JSON.parse(eventsArrayJSON);
  if (events.length > 0) this.setState({ events })
}

filterHandler = filter => ...

nothingToShow() {
  return (
    <div className="w3-container">
      <div className="w3-panel">
        <h1>Nessun Evento da mostrare</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

render() {
  const { events, showAllEvents, showUnmappedEvents } = this.state
  return (
    <div>
      <EventsHeader filterHandler={this.filterHandler}/>
      <div id="eventToShowContainer">
        {events.map(e => (
          <Event
            key={e.name}
            eventName={e.name} 
            eventPhoto={e.photo} 
            eventPeriods={e.periods} 
            eventDescription={e.description}
            eventTag={e.tag}
            eventIsDraft={showAllEvents}
            eventIsMapped={showUnmappedEvents}
          />
        ))}
        {events.length === 0 && this.nothingToShow()}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This way every time your parent state changes the children will get updated `eventIsDraft` and `eventIsMapped` props, because every state change implies re-render.

---

The way you're doing it now:

> initial parent's `render` to render container div `->` `componentDidMount` `->` `getElementById` to find container `->` `ReactDOM.render` into that container`

-- is obsolete with React, now you need to forget everything related to imperative DOM changes (hello, jQuery, and bye!), leave it all in 2014, and dive into a wonderful world of explicit state management and declarative UIs.

My proposed solution logic is next:

> initial render will render `nothingToShow` `->` `componentDidMount` will `setState` if there are any events in `localStorage` `->` `setState` will trigger `render` `->` now, if events are in state, `render` will draw our array of `Event` components

And, on event of filter change:

> `filterHandler` calls `setState` `->` `setState` triggers `render` -> `render` reads updated `this.state` and renders `Event`'s with updated `EventIsDraft` and `EventIsMapped` props

Since now `Event` component receives actual props from parent all the time, we don't need it to have local state, so it becomes as simple as:

```
const Event = props => props.showUnmapped && (
  <div className="w3-container">
    <div className="eventPanel w3-panel">
      <h1>name: {props.name}</h1>
      <h6>description: {props.description}</h6>
      <h6>{props.periods[0]}</h6>
      <h6>{props.tag[0]}</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

PS: not sure how are you separating draft/mapped events, since your code didn't reflect it clearly

Comment: I understand your propose, but I can't to update the events state in componentDidMount, do you have some suggest?

Comment: Actually I'm using a loop and this sintax for update the state 'events: [...prevState.events, eventsArray[i]]', but don't work

Comment: Why can't you update events state in `cDM`? Can you just read them from `localStorage` and call `setState`? `for` loop is redundant for this task

Comment: I'm trying but  after the call to setState I call console.log(this.state.events.length) and the result is zero.
I'm sure that in eventsArray there is something because I print its content in the console

Comment: if your `console.log(this.state.events.length)` is inside of `componentDidMount` then of course it will render zero, because `setState` update is asynchronous (it is on React, when to apply new state). Instead of this, you should place your `console.log` in render method, which is called with updated state.

Comment: ops...I didn't know that